# django not switching to Postres when deploying to Heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I deployed my django app with Heroku and I am having troubles with connecting to Postgres.

If I run `python manage.py createsuperuser` after running `heroku ps:exec --app produceit` (so I am inside the Heroku instance's terminal), it says that I successfully created a superuser but nothing is written into Heroku Postgress DB...so I can't login into neither `/admin` nor my app.

I therefore run

```
heroku ps:exec --app produceit
python manage.py shell
from mywebsite.settings import DATABASES
```

and it seems like the settings.py has the variable DATABASE still connected to sqlite (see pic)
[image]

Funny enough, if I hardcode an admin into Heroku's Postgres DB, loging and then create an instance of one of my models from the app itself (like I create a blog's post)...it actually writes into Postgres and I see it on the Front End.

So basically it's like the app is working on Postgress BUT the terminal is running on SQLite.

What can I do?  My settings are below

```
    """
Django settings for mywebsite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG=True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'produceit.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'action.apps.ActionConfig',
    'django_extensions',
    'bootstrap_modal_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mywebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mywebsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

#DATABASES = {
#    'default': {
#                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
#                'NAME': '',
#                'HOST': '',
#                'PORT': 5432,
#                'USER': '',
#                'PASSWORD': '',
#            }
#        }



# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
#import dj_database_url
#db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
#DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
#DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

import django_on_heroku
django_on_heroku.settings(locals())

#SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT=True
#SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True
#CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True
#SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 31536000
#SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=True
#SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=True

#import django_heroku
#django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: It looks like your environment variables are wrong in the terminal. Does "echo "$DATABASE_URL" " do anything?

Comment: or just "echo $DATABASE_URL" I'm not sure

Comment: First of all, beware of sharing secret credentials like the secret key and database credentials. It probably isn't a production ready site but nonetheless. Secondly, I assume you are aware that you commented out the DATABASES variable in your settings.py corresponding to your Postgres database right?

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct environment variables etc., connect to the terminal via the Heroku dashboard and try it again. You can find it in "More" > "Run Console" > Type in "Bash" on your Heroku-app.